# How prove this eigenvalue inequality $|z|\le na,|x|\le nh,|y|\le nk$

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A_{n\times n}=({a_{ij}})_{n\times n},H=({h_{ij}})_{n\times n},K=(k_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is complex matrix,and  can $A=H+K$,where $H=\overline{H}^T,K=-\overline{K}^T$

and let 
$$a=\max{(|a_{ij}|)},h=\max{(|h_{ij}|)},k=\max{(|k_{ij}|)},i,j=1,2,\cdots,n$$
and $z=x+yi$ is $A$ eigenvalue,

show that
$$|z|\le na,|x|\le nh,|y|\le nk$$

My try:we konw this inequality 
 $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \left| {\lambda _k } \right|^2   \leqslant \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \left| {a_{ij} } \right|^2  .
$$
where $\lambda_{k}$ is $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ eigenvalue.

maybe $|z|<a,|x|<h,|y|<nk$ is true

But my problem is different this .

Thank you  very much

Comment: The statement is right ? Maybe $ 
|z|\leq a,\ |x|\leq h,\ |y|\leq k$

Comment: Yes,maybe is true.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$  H = \frac{A+\overline{A}^T}{2},\ K= A-H$$

If $Av=zv$ then we have a representation :

$A$ is upper triangular matrix with $A_{11}=z$

Hence $x=H_{11}$ and $iy=K_{11}$

So $$ |z|\leq a,\ |x|\leq h,\ |y|\leq k$$

Comment: then? Thank you